# static const char [] in class thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, static, constants, mutex

Are `static const`'s in a class thread safe? In the code below I have `trailingBytesForUTF8` which is a `static const` character array. There may be many threads having their own object instance of the `CConvertUTF` class. Will there be any mutable state issues when multiple threads are accessing the same `trailingBytesForUTF8` array at the same time, or any other threading issues? Also note that threads will *never* share the same object instance of the `CConvertUTF` class.

```
// .h
class CConvertUTF final
{
    private:
        static const char trailingBytesForUTF8[256];
    public:
        bool IsLegalUTF8Sequence(const char *source, const char *sourceEnd);
        bool IsLegalUTF8(const char *source, int length);
};

// .cpp
const char CConvertUTF::trailingBytesForUTF8[256] = {
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5
};

bool CConvertUTF::IsLegalUTF8Sequence(const char *source, const char *sourceEnd) {
    int length = trailingBytesForUTF8[*source]+1;
    if (source+length > sourceEnd) {
    return false;
    }
    return IsLegalUTF8(source, length);
}

bool CConvertUTF::IsLegalUTF8(const char *source, int length) {
    char a;
    const *char = source+length;
    switch (length) {
    default: return false;
    /* Everything else falls through when "true"... */
    case 4: if ((a = (*--srcptr)) < 0x80 || a > 0xBF) return false;
    case 3: if ((a = (*--srcptr)) < 0x80 || a > 0xBF) return false;
    case 2: if ((a = (*--srcptr)) > 0xBF) return false;

    switch (*source) {
        /* no fall-through in this inner switch */
        case 0xE0: if (a < 0xA0) return false; break;
        case 0xED: if (a > 0x9F) return false; break;
        case 0xF0: if (a < 0x90) return false; break;
        case 0xF4: if (a > 0x8F) return false; break;
        default:   if (a < 0x80) return false;
    }

    case 1: if (*source >= 0x80 && *source < 0xC2) return false;
    }
    if (*source > 0xF4) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: (Hmm.  Given `const char test[] = { 0xA, 0xFF, 0xA }; IsLegalUTF8Sequence(test, test+3)` is `true`.)

Comment: @aschepler Thanks for debugging, the code is the old open source code from Unicode Inc. that I have just added a object-oriented programming style to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read-only (const) variables are always thread safe until the moment they are destroyed. Since a static object is only destroyed at program termination, they are good for the life of the program.

The only exception would be an object with a `mutable` member, but that doesn't apply to a `char` array.

Comment: Submitter's example is (probably) thread-safe since it will (probably) be initialized before any new threads are created, but variables are not reliably thread-safe without mutex locks, even if they have a const, or even a static const in front of them, even if they appear in global space (since you don't have control over initalization order). I think this is fixed in C++11.

Comment: @Scott I based my answer on an assumption that those variables would be initialized *before* any alternate threads could be started. In hindsight it's possible that another static initialization could start a thread, or a static variable could be at block level (inside a function) rather than class level. For static const POD types it makes no difference, because the universal method of initializing them is to put their contents into the code space that gets loaded before execution begins.

Comment: Agreed. I don't know if the standard guarantees this, but static POD is very likely to exist before any code is run. Note that if a *pointer* itself isn't const (points to const data but is itself non-const) then the pointer may not be initialized before main(). I only brought all that up because we recently got bit by a singleton class (used my multiple threads) with lazy static initialization (i.e. C::instance() { static C instance; return instance; }), two threads used the singleton "for the first time" and ran the constructor concurrently--fortunately a seg-fault helped us find the bug.

Answer (score 3):

any data which is specified as `static const` is global and read only.

This means that are protected from race conditions since no one will ever modify the data.

For a data race condition to appear there must be at least on write operation

Comment: The compiler will probably generate thread-safe code to just "say" that the variable points to a blob of data before any other objects are initialized, but since initialization order is not guaranteed, there is a multi-thread danger even with "static const" data. I think this is fixed in C++11.